# why there are missing rpms when installing the same rhel ISO on different machines

Tags: linux, redhat, kernel, rpm, iso

we have a very strange behavior after installing new machines with rhel 7.x ( FROM ISO INSTALLER )

we notice that rpm - `libcgroup` , isn't installed on the current new machines

while before couple month on other machines this rpm - `libcgroup` was installed

I want to say that we also check if this rpm was removed , but this isn't the case

**we not sure but** , is it possible that **Anaconda installer** in some cases decided not installed specific rpm as `libcgroup`  ??

is it possible because different HW ? or other scenario ?

Comment: Are you using the same minor release? 7.9 is current, while 7.8 was current some months ago. The latest 7.8 patches also include everything from 7.9 - except the release-file. So what are the (initial) kernel-versions of your installed machines?

Comment: we use only the ISO for rhel 7.6 with kernel - 3.10.0-957 ,

Comment: yes I know what I am saying is strange , but we are using the same iso 7.6 , so not clearly why on latest machines the rpm that I mentioned not installed and on previos machine they are installed

Comment: Compare the generated `anaconda-ks.cfg` files from each installation.